# How to add Authorizarion for Archiva Repositoty in Maven?

Tags: maven, archiva

I am using Maven for my project everything work fine but now i need some third party jar which are not available on Maven Central repository.
So i installed **Archiva** in my server and added **Archiva** repository entry in **pom.xml** file

```
<repository>
            <id>internal</id>
            <name>Archiva Managed Internal Repository</name>
            <url>http://ipaddress:8888/repository/internal/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
</repository>
```

But when i am running **mvn** command i am getting

```
>  Could not transfer artifact
> org.jbosscaches:jboss-common-core:pom:2.2.19.GA from/to internal
> (http://ipaddress:8999/repository/internal/): Not authorized ,
> ReasonPhrase:Unauthorized. -> [Help 1
```

What changes i have to do maven **settings.xml** file

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://archiva.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/userguide/deploy.html.
I'm pretty sure this will help you :-)

Olivier